# Open multiple CSV files, sort and filter the data from each one, place in master spreadsheet Macro/VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to:

- open up spreadsheets from a folder of 50
- sort and filter the first sheet on each one (the name will be unknown of this sheet)
- filtering needs to find each row that has a certain value in column J - this value is 'No'
- All rows that meet the criteria (row J contains 'no') need to be then placed onto a master spreadsheet
- Each csv should close each time it's been processed

I have spent hours & hours on forums and have some code which I have been tinkering with, but can't get it running together:

```
 Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.csv*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
    
   
   Range("A1:AC3100").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=1
    Range("Y2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$3110").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:="No"
    Range("A1:AC3100").Select
    Range("Y2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown


    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The spreadsheet data has variable lengths do I made the selection the maximum:

```
Range("A1:AC3100")
```

I would assume there is a better way than this too.

Comment: I'd take a look at [MSDN Library: Much ADO about Text Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .... basically you can read the csv data into ADO Recordsets with a SQL Query, and filter, sort the data before dumping it into your worksheet (using `CopyFromRecordset`)

Comment: Additionally you can get the query you need built for you by using MS Query inside Excel (*From Other Sources > From Microsoft Query* in **Data** tab)

Comment: if you can provide some sample of the data in your csv files, I can build you a sample to get started with...

Comment: I found an earlier answer I gave on this type of thing: [SO: 18707320/how-can-i-import-a-month-of-csv-files-date-named-into-excel-via-vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707320/how-can-i-import-a-month-of-csv-files-date-named-into-excel-via-vba/18714444#18714444)

Answer (score 1):

Your criterion is a bit too vague to give a perfect response, but I'll take a crack at it. Some parts of your code seem extraneous or convoluted so I'm doing this based on your end goal (all rows where the value in column J for the first sheet in each workbook that contain 'no' are copied into a master spreadsheet).

If all of your worksheets are always in the same folder you can make the myPath static rather than attempting to use the msoFileDialogFolderPicker. When I attempted to run your code on my machine it gave me an ***"Out of Memory"*** error, if you have this issue as well I recommend a static string for myPath.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PutInMasterFile()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim masterWB As Workbook
Dim rowNum As Integer
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim c As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

I would advise against disabling Events until you have confirmed your code is running correctly. Worry about getting working code before thinking about optimization.

```
x = 1
Set masterWB = Workbooks("NAMEOFWORKBOOK")
Set pasteRange = masterWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & x)
myPath = "C:\EXAMPLE\MOREEXAMPLE\*.csv"
myFile = Dir(myPath)
```

myPath can be set to search directly for .csv files in the string.

```
Do While myFile <> vbNullString

    Workbooks.Open (myFile)
    
    With Workbooks(myFile).Sheets(1)
        
        Set c = .Range("J:J").Find("No", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Using .find in vba is preferential to trying to get a filter and then grabbing everything that the filter displays.

```
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
        
            FirstAddress = c.Address
            
            Do
            
            rowNum = c.Row
            Set copyRange = .Range(rowNum & ":" & rowNum)
            copyRange.Copy
            pasteRange.PasteSpecial
            x = x + 1
            Set pasteRange = masterWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & x)
```

Copies in the row into your master sheet. The x = x + 1 guarantees you paste new data onto a new row to avoid overwriting anything.

```
            Set c = .Range("J:J").FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And FirstAddress <> c.Address
        
        End If
    End With

Workbooks(myFile).Close
myFile = Dir()
```

Closes your first file and gets the next one set up

```
Set pasteRange = masterWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & x)
```

Sets the paste range in the master wb outside of the inner loop, otherwise it will overwrite the values starting at A1 again with the next file.

```
Loop

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I would also recommend you read up on VBA best practices for any future code you work on such as using Option Explicit and avoiding use of GoTo or .Select wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I am trying to run it now, what do I put in here: "NAMEOFWORKBOOK". I tried adding a workbook to the folder that the csvs are in but this doens't work. I get 'subscript out of range' and this is highlighted.

Comment: This would be the name of the "master" workbook that is getting all the data transferred into it.

Comment: It stops at this each time and highlights it yellow, whether I put full filepath in : "c:\users\myname\desktop\files\Book1.xlsx" or whether I just add the file without the path.

Comment: To clarify, this looks for workbooks currently open in Excel with that particular file name as a string (e.g. if I have a report MasterReport.xlsx in my directory that I have opened in Excel, the value for masterWB would be "MasterReport".) It will not look in a directory for you and does not open any files.

Comment: It is possible to have it open a specific file in your directory if necessary but the code structure would need to change to accommodate it. If you really need this functionality then this should get you started, otherwise manually opening the master file before running your macro is the way to go.

    Dim myMasterFile as string --
    myMasterFile = "C:\Example\MasterReport.xlsx" --
    Workbooks.Open(myMasterFile) --
    Set masterWB = Workbooks("MasterReport")

Comment: This doesn't crash but doesn't do anything. Nothing happens at all, could you perhaps send me a zip of the files you got to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133292/discussion-between-orou-and-rich-stevens).