# VBA: How read csv file with different structure line?

Tags: vba, file, csv

I want to read data from csv file, but just from line 3 to line 13, where line have same number of elements (6).

Line 1 have 1 element/line (date time) - no comma after first element.

Line 2 have 2 elements/line (number, number) - no comma after second element.

Line 3 to 13 have 6 elements/line (no.1, no.2, no.3....no.6).

Line 14 - to end of file is not interested for me.
Because first 2 lines is different for next (3-13), I receive a error: "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range."

I try to separate reading line, but program beak at line mark with **

What can I do for skip over to this?

This is code:

```
Sub OpenTextFile()
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open FilePath For Input As #1

For row_number = 0 To 10
   '     LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    If row_number = 0 Then
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
    End If
    If row_number = 1 Then
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
    End If
    If row_number >= 1 Then
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
      **ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(2)** ' here break the program
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 4).Value = LineItems(3)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 5).Value = LineItems(4)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 5).Value = LineItems(5)
    End If
Next row_number
Close #1
End Sub
```

and this is a csv file example:

```
2018/03/27 13:31:52
58.05372,240.2784
30.45,1115.922,88135,0.05049,24.85,33.85
61.9,1662.875,102416,0.5585,56.5,68.5
79.3,1434.352,117602.5,0.10008,72.5,87
93.25,2398.221,225121.5,0.19968,87,104
0,0,0,0,99,100
142.5,388.493,55185.5,0.05043,122.5,158
168.05,261.3842,29628,0.05035,156,175
222.9,305.9312,1955185,0.5479,206,238
226.55,29088.84,1957502,97.045,207,239
261.4,373.4588,36588,0.29764,250.6,267.6
275.15,1440.946,168334,1.1001,268.175,288.5
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Can't you just *open* the file to a new worksheet and deal with it from there? Excel's *made* for CSV's!  You're duplicating functionality that's already built-in.

Comment: [`Workbooks.OpenText` Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) **and** SO: [How can I import a month of csv files (date named) into Excel via VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707320/how-can-i-import-a-month-of-csv-files-date-named-into-excel-via-vba)

Comment: I want to take data from 8 similar csv files, put them in Excel and do a statistical analysis on data of the same type.
In fact, I need column 1 and column 4 from the data package.
We automate the reading of csv files and then perform a statistical analysis on the two types of columns, from 8 different csv files.
In my example I wanted to test the reading mode and noticed this jam.
I'm sure it's caused from the different csv file structure, but I do not know how to fix it. I do not even know if a csv with a homogeneous structure can be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine without the file - I made it print `XXXX`'s in the cells it's trying to populate and got this:

[image: img]

---

I'm taking a bit of a shot in the dark here but...

Perhaps instead of this:

```
If row_number >= 1 Then
```

you meant to you use *greater than*?:

```
If row_number > 1 Then
```

?

---

But note that your code will start populating cells at whichever cell is highlighted (instead of using absolute references), for example if I select `D10` and run your code, then `D10` will be the top-left corner.

Also not all your variables are declared.  Use `Option Explicit` a at the top of [every] module [forever] to help identify problems like undeclared variables and mishandled objects.

---

**With those changes:**

[image: img]

**Other things to check out:**

- MSDN: [**`Workbooks.OpenText` Method (Excel)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel)
- Stack Overflow: [**How can I import a month of csv files (date named) into Excel via VBA?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707320/how-can-i-import-a-month-of-csv-files-date-named-into-excel-via-vba)

Comment: It works!
Thank you very much.
We've declared all the variables and modified "> 1" instead of "> = 1"

Thank you very much for your help!